# Unit testing suspend coroutine

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

a bit new to Kotlin and testing it... I am trying to test a dao object wrapper with using a suspend method which uses an awaitFirst() for an SQL return object. However, when I wrote the unit test for it, it is just stuck in a loop. And I would think it is due to the awaitFirst() is not in the same scope of the testing

Implementation:

```
suspend fun queryExecution(querySpec: DatabaseClient.GenericExecuteSpec): OrderDomain {
        var result: Map<String, Any>?
        try {
            result = querySpec.fetch().first().awaitFirst()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            if (e is DataAccessResourceFailureException)
                throw CommunicationException(
                    "Cannot connect to " + DatabaseConstants.DB_NAME +
                        DatabaseConstants.ORDERS_TABLE + " when executing querySelect",
                    "querySelect",
                    e
                )
            throw InternalException("Encountered R2dbcException when executing SQL querySelect", e)
        }

        if (result == null)
            throw ResourceNotFoundException("Resource not found in Aurora DB")

        try {
            return OrderDomain(result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw InternalException("Exception when parsing to OrderDomain entity", e)
        } finally {
            logger.info("querySelect;stage=end")
        }
    }
```

Unit Test:

```
@Test
    fun `get by orderid id, null`() = runBlocking {
        // Assign
        Mockito.`when`(fetchSpecMock.first()).thenReturn(monoMapMock)
        Mockito.`when`(monoMapMock.awaitFirst()).thenReturn(null)

        // Act & Assert
        val exception = assertThrows<ResourceNotFoundException> {
            auroraClientWrapper.queryExecution(
                databaseClient.sql("SELECT * FROM orderTable WHERE orderId=:1").bind("1", "123") orderId
            )
        }
        assertEquals("Resource not found in Aurora DB", exception.message)
    }
```

I noticed this issue on https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1204 but none of the work around has worked for me...

Using runBlocking within Unit Test just causes my tests to never complete. Using runBlockingTest explicitly throws an error saying "Job never completed"... Anyone has any idea? Any hack at this point?

Also I fairly understand the point of you should not be using suspend with a block because that kinda defeats the purposes of suspend since it is releasing the thread to continue later versus blocking forces the thread to wait for a result... But then how does this work?

```
private suspend fun queryExecution(querySpec: DatabaseClient.GenericExecuteSpec): Map {
        var result: Map<String, Any>?
        try {
            result = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                querySpec.fetch().first().block()
            }
return result
}
```

Does this mean withContext will utilize a new thread, and re-use the old thread elsewhere? Which then doesnt really optimize anything since I will still have one thread that is being blocked regardless of spawning a new context?

Comment: Mocking coroutine functions may be tricky.  Consider using a fake instead.  And the answer to your second question is that correctly implemented coroutine code suspends instead of blocking, which does not lock up a thread.  (With the effect that, yes, the old thread will be used elsewhere.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you for your input, could you please expand on using a fake? The thing is I still need to intercept that awaitFirst(). Or do you mean give a real value for the first() interception instead of a mock, and let awaitFirst() apply on the real value instead?

Comment: I mean creating an implementation of the `DatabaseClient.GenericExecuteSpec` type, _without mocking_, that returns test values passed in at construction.

Comment: @LouisWasserman However, this GenericExecuteSpec hits a DB - if I were to create an implementation without mocking, it would have to be live data which kind of defeats the Unit Test intention.

Comment: Make one that doesn't hit a DB.  Or make a fake, in-memory DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

The `monoMapMock` is a mock value from Mockito. Seems like the kotlinx-test coroutines can't intercept an async to return a mono. So I forced the method that I can mock, to return a real Mono value instead of a Mocked Mono. To do so, as suggested by Louis. I  stop mocking it and return a real value

```
@Test
    fun `get by orderid id, null`() = runBlocking {
        // Assign
        Mockito.`when`(fetchSpecMock.first()).thenReturn(Mono.empty())
        Mockito.`when`(monoMapMock.awaitFirst()).thenReturn(null)

        // Act & Assert
        val exception = assertThrows<ResourceNotFoundException> {
            auroraClientWrapper.queryExecution(
                databaseClient.sql("SELECT * FROM orderTable WHERE orderId=:1").bind("1", "123") orderId
            )
        }
        assertEquals("Resource not found in Aurora DB", exception.message)
    }
```